# Retrieve data from two tables

Tags: mysql, join, parse-platform

i want to retrieve data from two tables in parse. I have searched about this but fail to find some query for it. Please help me out.

Comment: search for `mysql join`

Comment: as i mentioned above that i am working in parse.com

Comment: How do you plan on using the data, can you provide some preliminary code so we can get a sense of how the data will be used.